# How can I display the image correctly on the right side of my navigation bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I am attaching my fiddle. When you look at it, at the top right corner you will see "Account" and "Logout". Instead of the "Logout" text, I want there to be an "off" image that you will find in the CSS portion. How do i do that?

`URL:`https://jsfiddle.net/mikoo1991/pk6baz1z/1/embedded/result/

Comment: I don't understand the issue, Do you think you can try again ? maybe post in a picture what you expect to see ?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/nalosfo33/

I want the image to be where the arrow is pointing, instead of the text "Logout"

Answer (score 1):

The other answers here address your issue which was that you forgot to add the id in your html. However, I'd like to point out that adding a background image like this is not the best way to accomplish the desired results.

Honestly, you'd be better off using icons like [FontAwesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/get-started/) for this, this is exactly what they are made for:

Simply add this to your head tag:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">`

OR add this to your css file:

`@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');`

And then the updated html would look like this:
`<li><a href="#">Logout<i class="fa fa-power-off mar-l-10"></i>`

---

**Here is what you'd get:**

[image]

#### Here is an updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/pk6baz1z/9/)

I made some tweaks to your CSS to make it look good with the icon. Also, I changed your `height:7%` on the header to 55px. IMHO, using a percentage for a header is a bad idea as it will shrink too much on mobile devices and most headers are a fixed height anyway so setting it explicitly is usually safe.

If you want just the icon, simply remove the text and adjust the padding/font-size if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you were trying to embed a container inside a list item.

The list item only allows inline elements to be embedded i.e. span, a.

If you use logout-btn as the ID in the a tag, you will see the image show up (additional styling will be required).

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Account</a></li>
  <li><a id="logout-btn" href="#">
  </a></li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk6baz1z/4/)  -- Solely an example of the image displaying -- I did no extra styling to get the image to display where it needs to be.

Comment: That is true, although I dont know how to style the rest

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a id="logout-btn" href="#">
....
</a></li>
```

I just added the id do to your link tag and added `....` characters in the html list item to add width to the image background.then turned the opactiy to zero,removed float right, and a few other styles applied, see below.

```
#logout-btn {
border: 0px solid black;
background-image:url('https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/token/128/Power-Shutdown.png');
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pk6baz1z/7/embedded/result/)

Comment: You should edit your answer to reflect the changes, not just leave a comment

Comment: That works, kind of. The right side of the image is cut off though.

Comment: i updated it to not cut off the right side. see the above answer, with my updated info and updated fiddle link.

Comment: using the `@import` method as shown in @delightedD0D answer isn't b for best results for page load speed, also including a new css `<link>` with a cdn would be to much for just one icon. See [here](https://gtmetrix.com/avoid-css-import.html) for why to not use `@import`